# Pointing domain to custom DNSs which contain the domain

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver

I need to change the DNSs of my domain, and I'm getting an error that the DNSs aren't registered. Maybe they simply haven't propogated yet, but it ocurred to me that what I'm doing seems kind of recursive. If my domain is example.com and my DNSs are ns1.example.com and ns2.example.com, is there a problem with doing that? It seems like I'm trying to point the domain to itself. And in case you're wondering, I didn't set up the custom DNSs. My hosting company did it when they created the account.

I tried using the IP addresses, but I got an error, saying "invalid TLD."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create "[glue records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#Circular_dependencies_and_glue_records)" at your domain registrar.